# How to run a few Docker Compose with similar names of images?

Tags: docker, server, docker-compose, droplet

I have >10 projects with similar architecture, but not identical. Names of images in docker-compose are the same. So I need to run all of them on one droplet. How can I run it with out conflicts?

Comment: What have you tried and what errors did you encounter? Please include a [mcve].

Comment: If you're on Linux, you can create multiple directories and create a soft link of one of them into each directory, then run each docker compose file. The names will be `directoryName_serviceName`

Comment: @BMitch For example this: https://github.com/kosyachniy/web . If I duplicate this project in one droplet and run, they fall.

Comment: @Saeed Yes, Linux. But how can I create a soft link? Which commands?

Comment: How do you know they fail? What errors did you encounter? Please update your question with the steps you are performing, and issues you are seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker compose uses the current directoy as "project name", for example:

```sh
cd foo
docker-compose up
```

This will create every service declared as `foo_<servicename>_1`.

You can specify a parameter on `docker-compose` changing the default project name for each compose file:

```sh
docker-compose --file mycompose.yml --project-name anyname up
```

> `--file` can be `-f` and `--project-name` can be `-p`

Comment: The project name is included in container names (assuming you don't unnecessarily override them with `container_name:`).  You'd typically see container names like `project_service_1`.

Comment: @DavidMaze You are right. I used to ` container_name `. With out it, everything work!

Answer (score 0):

Since your containers cannot have exact the same name, but you can use **directory prefixing** names using by default.

Let us imagine you have this directory structure:

```
/home/your_project_directory/1/
/home/your_project_directory/2/
/home/your_project_directory/3/
/home/your_project_directory/4/
```

In directory `1` you have a `docker-compose.yml` file with the below contents:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
    httpd:
        image: nginx
        restart: always
volumes:
    nginx: {}
```

Suppose you are in directory `/home/your_project_directory/` .

Now let's `cd` into each of these four directories and run this command:

```
ln -s /home/your_project_directory/2/docker-compose.yml $PWD/2
```

This will create a soft link from `docker-compose.yml` file in directory `1` into `2`.

And repeat this command for the two other directories `3` and `4`.

When you have done all of them, you can verify each of them by this command:

```
find /home/your_project_directory/ -name 'docker-compose.yml' ls -lh {} \;
```

This command **find**s in directory **/home/your_project_directory/** any file called **docker-compose.yml** and then runs **ls -lh THAT_FILE**, as below:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 105 Apr 23 04:20 /home/your_project_directory/1/docker-compose.yml
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Apr 23 04:11 /home/your_project_directory/2/docker-compose.yml -> /home/your_project_directory/1/docker-compose.yml
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Apr 23 04:11 /home/your_project_directory/3/docker-compose.yml -> /home/your_project_directory/1/docker-compose.yml
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Apr 23 04:12 /home/your_project_directory/4/docker-compose.yml -> /home/your_project_directory/1/docker-compose.yml
```

Good, now let's make them all up by another `find` command:

```
find . -name "docker-compose.yml" -exec docker-compose -f {} up -d \;
```

Again, this file finds any file named `docker-compose.yml` and then runs `docker-compose -f THAT_FILE up -d` command.

So, these four command would run:

```
docker-compose -f 1/docker-compose.yml up -d
docker-compose -f 2/docker-compose.yml up -d
docker-compose -f 3/docker-compose.yml up -d
docker-compose -f 4/docker-compose.yml up -d
```

And if you run `docker ps`, you should see similar output:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE              COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS     NAMES
4dac5dfba581   nginx              "/docker-entrypoint.…"   12 minutes ago   Up 12 minutes   80/tcp    1_httpd_1
d517a156f6a1   nginx              "/docker-entrypoint.…"   12 minutes ago   Up 12 minutes   80/tcp    2_httpd_1
ed6223ca5411   nginx              "/docker-entrypoint.…"   12 minutes ago   Up 12 minutes   80/tcp    3_httpd_1
0fa78f2ba8bf   nginx              "/docker-entrypoint.…"   12 minutes ago   Up 12 minutes   80/tcp    4_httpd_1
```

But per your needs and your requirements, you can add any details to your `docker-compose.yml` file.

**Note** that you cannot use the same port mapping in this file, as you get port already allocated error.

The other approach is to `cp` one file into other three directories and use port mapping with different ports, like in `1/docker-compose.yml`:

```
ports:
    - "8080:80"
```

And `2/docker-compose.yml`:

```
ports:
    - "8081:80"
```

etc.